# Programatically change all renderings with specific rendering parameter

Tags: powershell-extensions

I'm new to Sitecore PowerShell and would like to know the best way to get all the items on my content tree that have a specific rendering parameter set so I can replace it with another value in the rendering parameter.
I know I can replace the layout IDs but I thought of using PowerShell to create a more elegant solution.

I reviewed the documentation on Get-Rendering and Set-Rendering but couldn't get the script to work. Here is what I have so far. Any help is highly appreciated

```
 $defaultLayout = Get-LayoutDevice "Default"
$path = "master:\sitecore\content\home\page-that-has-rendering"
$language = 'en-US'
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Language $language -Recurse
$newValue = Get-Item -Path 'master:\sitecore\content\home\path-to-mynewrenderingparametervalue'
$items | ForEach-Object {
    
    $rendering = Get-Rendering -Id $_.ID -Device $defaultLayout -FinalLayout 
    
    #$param = Get-RenderingParameter -Rendering $rendering | Format-Table -Auto
    foreach($itemRendering in Get-Rendering -Item $_ -FinalLayout) {

        $parameters = Get-RenderingParameter -Rendering $itemRendering
        Set-Rendering -Instance $newValue     
        
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the path that you have for `$newValue`? Is that another item that you're copying the rendering parameters from?

Comment: yes, that's the rendering parameter I'm trying to set it to.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code, I have modified the custom rendering parameter like the `Ajax Options` check box.

In this, the function takes as an input item you want to edit and field - either Final or Shared layout.

Also Write a log on every step:-

```
$languages = @('en')

$startPath = '/sitecore/content/xxx/xxx/Presentation/Partial Designs/Frenchs/Recipe'

$renderingNames = @('Menu Wrapper')

$renderingParamterToUpdate = "Ajax Call"

$newRenderingParameterValue = "0"




foreach($language in $languages){

    $items = Get-ChildItem -Path $startPath -Language $language -Recurse

    foreach($item in $items){

        Write-Host 'Updating Item: ' $item.Paths.FullPath

        foreach($itemRendering in Get-Rendering -Item $item -FinalLayout) {

            $renderingItem = Get-Item -Path master: -ID $itemRendering.ItemID    

            if($renderingNames -contains $renderingItem.Name){

                Write-Host 'Found Rendering: ' $($renderingItem.Name)                

                $parameters = Get-RenderingParameter -Rendering $itemRendering

                if($parameters[$renderingParamterToUpdate] -ne $newRenderingParameterValue){

                    Write-Host 'Updating' $renderingParamterToUpdate -ForegroundColor Green

                    $parameters[$renderingParamterToUpdate] = $newRenderingParameterValue

                    $itemRendering | Set-RenderingParameter -Parameter $parameters |

                    Set-Rendering -Item $item -FinalLayout

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code snippet. I am not using build-in cmdlets but Sitecore API only.

Function takes as an input **item** that you want to edit and **field** - either `Final` or `Shared` layout.

Rendering parameter name and value are hardcoded inside function. Modify it to your specific needs.

```bsh
function Set-RenderingParametersForField($item, $fieldID) {
    $laytoutField = New-Object "Sitecore.Data.Fields.LayoutField" $item.Fields[$fieldID]
    $modified = $false
    $definition = [Sitecore.Layouts.LayoutDefinition]::Parse($laytoutField.Value)
    $definition.Devices | % {
        $_.Renderings | % {
            $par = [Sitecore.Web.WebUtil]::ParseUrlParameters($_.Parameters)
            $renderingParameter = $par["RENDERING_PARAMETER_FIELD_NAME"]
            if ($renderingParameter -ne $null) {
                $par["RENDERING_PARAMETER_FIELD_NAME"] = "NEW VALUE"
                $_.Parameters = (New-Object "Sitecore.Text.UrlString" $par).GetUrl()
                $modified = $true
            }
        }
    }
    if ($modified) {
        $item.Editing.BeginEdit()
        $laytoutField.Value = $definition.ToXml()
        $item.Editing.EndEdit() > $null
    }
}

Set-RenderingParametersForField $currentItem ([Sitecore.FieldIDs]::LayoutField)
Set-RenderingParametersForField $currentItem ([Sitecore.FieldIDs]::FinalLayoutField)
```

Comment: Thank you Alan. This is helpful although I'm looking for a way to get this done through powershell commands

Comment: Fine, if it makes all the things easier :)
btw. underneath exactly the same code is being used https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/blob/master/src/Spe/Commands/Presentation/GetRenderingParameterCommand.cs